# How do you create a SQL expression to calculate the total of multiple data fields?

Tags: sql, list, sum, report, expression

I am trying to add the final data fields in each row of a list report.  These data fields tally the number of hours worked by an applicant.  The desired result is that the expression displays a total of 442 hours.  This is due to the fact that the first field value is 420 hours and the second field value is 22 hours.  The other field values are zero.  In the first example below, the report generates a concatenation of the characters, 420220000.

**=Fields!EstHrsTotal1.Value+Fields!EstHrsTotal2.Value+Fields!EstHrsTotal3.Value+Fields!EstHrsTotal4.Value+Fields!EstHrsTotal5.Value+Fields!EstHrsTotal6.Value**

In the second example, using the SUM operator results in #Error in the report.

**=SUM(Fields!EstHrsTotal1.Value+Fields!EstHrsTotal2.Value+Fields!EstHrsTotal3.Value+Fields!EstHrsTotal4.Value+Fields!EstHrsTotal5.Value+Fields!EstHrsTotal6.Value)**

What is the correct method to caculate the sum of the total values for these six data fields?

Comment: The report is constructed in MS Report Builder.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your EstHrsTotal values are strings. You'll need to convert them to integer (or decimal if you will need to account for fractions of hours). You can do this in the sql or in the SSRS Report:

SQL:

```
select
    cast(EstHrsTotal1 as int) EstHrsTotal1,
    cast(EstHrsTotal2 as int) EstHrsTotal2,
    cast(EstHrsTotal3 as int) EstHrsTotal3,
    cast(EstHrsTotal4 as int) EstHrsTotal4,
    cast(EstHrsTotal5 as int) EstHrsTotal5,
    cast(EstHrsTotal6 as int) EstHrsTotal6
from dbo.YourTable
```

SSRS Report:

> **=CInt(Fields!EstHrsTotal1.Value)+CInt(Fields!EstHrsTotal2.Value)+CInt(Fields!EstHrsTotal3.Value)+CInt(Fields!EstHrsTotal4.Value)+CInt(Fields!EstHrsTotal5.Value)+CInt(Fields!EstHrsTotal6.Value)**

Comment: If my response answered your question, please consider marking it as an answer. Thank you! :)

Comment: How do you mark it as the best answer?  I don't see any buttons displayed to do so.

Comment: I've never asked a question here, but there is supposed to be a gray check mark next to my answer that you can click to toggle it green.

http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Thanks! :)